# Why in c++, a derived class template publicly Inherited from base class template can't call the base class' funtion directly?

Tags: c++, templates

This is the code:

```cpp
class A : public std::vector<int>
{
  public:
    void fooA()
    {
        std::cout << "A::fooA() + " << size() << '\n';
    }
};

template <typename T>
class B : std::vector<T>
{
  public:
    void fooB()
    {
        std::cout << "B::fooB() + " << size() << '\n';
    }
};
```

Class A is correct. 
But in class B, `size()` is considered undeclared, unless I change it to `std::vector<T>::size()`

Why doesn't class A have to add `std::vector<int>`, but does class B have to?

Comment: Alternatively, you can write `this->size()`.

Comment: Yes, it is more simple, but still can't call it directly.

Comment: FYI, on an unrelated note, it is not a good idea to derive from standard containers. They are not designed for inheritance. For instance, they don't have virtual destructors.